# Inserting each database row in different table rows?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a database with multiple rows of data in that I want displayed into a table but in different rows on a table but when there is multiple rows of data in the table it displays it on the same row and it doesnt have a + sign to expand.

[Hopefully this image can show you what I mean...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2O6X.png)

My code:

```
<?php
ob_start();
require_once 'includes/db.php';
require_once 'includes/init.php';
if (!($user -> LoggedIn()))
{
    header('location: login.php');
    die();
}
if (!($user -> notBanned($odb)))
{
    header('location: login.php');
    die();
}

include("header.php");
?><body>
<div class="page">
                <div class="mainwrapper">
                <div class="page-header">
      <h1 class="page-title">Methods</h1>
      <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="active">Methods</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
                <div class="page-content">
      <!-- Panel -->
      <div class="col-lg-12">
          <!-- Panel Filtering -->
          <div class="panel">
            <header class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title">Methods</h3>
            </header>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <table class="table table-bordered table-hover toggle-circle" id="exampleFootableFiltering">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th data-toggle="true">Method Title</th>
                    <th>Date Submitted</th>
                    <th data-hide="phone, tablet">Author</th>
                    <th data-hide="phone, tablet">Tutorial</th>
                    <th data-hide="phone, tablet">Status</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <div class="form-inline padding-bottom-15">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Status</label>
                        <select id="filteringStatus" class="form-control">
                          <option value="">Show all</option>
                          <option value="Working">Working</option>
                          <option value="Plausible">Plausible</option>
                          <option value="Not Working">Not Working</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input id="filteringSearch" type="text" placeholder="Search" class="form-control"
                        autocomplete="off">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <?php
                    $methodssql = $odb -> query("SELECT * FROM `methods`");
                    while($row = $methodssql ->fetch())
                    {
                    echo '<td>' . $row['m_title'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['sub_date'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['author'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['tutorial'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td> <span class="label label-table label-success"> ' . $row['status'] . ' </span> </td>';
                    }
                ?>

                  </tr>


                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="5">
                      <div class="text-right">
                        <ul class="pagination"></ul>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tfoot>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- End Panel Filtering -->
        </div>
          </div>

            </div>
            </div>


  <script>
    (function(document, window, $) {
      'use strict';

      var Site = window.Site;

      $(document).ready(function($) {
        Site.run();
      });

      // Example Row Toggler
      // -------------------
      (function() {
        $('#exampleRowToggler').footable();
      })();

      // Expand / Collapse All Rows
      // --------------------------
      (function() {
        var fooColExp = $('#exampleAccordion');
        fooColExp.footable().trigger('footable_expand_first_row');

        $('#exampleCollapseBtn').on('click', function() {
          fooColExp.trigger('footable_collapse_all');
        });
        $('#exampleExpandBtn').on('click', function() {
          fooColExp.trigger('footable_expand_all');
        })
      })();

      // Accordion
      // ---------
      (function() {
        $('#exampleFooAccordion').footable().on('footable_row_expanded',
          function(e) {
            $('#exampleFooAccordion tbody tr.footable-detail-show').not(
              e.row).each(function() {
              $('#exampleFooAccordion').data('footable').toggleDetail(
                this);
            });
          });
      })();

      // Pagination
      // ----------
      (function() {
        $('#examplePagination').footable();
        $('#exampleShow').change(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var pagesize = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
          $('#examplePagination').data('page-size', pagesize);
          $('#examplePagination').trigger('footable_initialized');
        });
      })();

      // Filtering
      // ---------
      (function() {
        var filtering = $('#exampleFootableFiltering');
        filtering.footable().on('footable_filtering', function(e) {
          var selected = $('#filteringStatus').find(':selected').val();
          e.filter += (e.filter && e.filter.length > 0) ? ' ' +
            selected : selected;
          e.clear = !e.filter;
        });

        // Filter status
        $('#filteringStatus').change(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          filtering.trigger('footable_filter', {
            filter: $(this).val()
          });
        });

        // Search input
        $('#filteringSearch').on('input', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          filtering.trigger('footable_filter', {
            filter: $(this).val()
          });
        });
      })();

      // Add & Remove Row
      // ----------------
      (function() {
        var addrow = $('#exampleFooAddRemove');
        addrow.footable().on('click', '.delete-row-btn', function() {

          //get the footable object
          var footable = addrow.data('footable');

          //get the row we are wanting to delete
          var row = $(this).parents('tr:first');

          //delete the row
          footable.removeRow(row);
        });

        // Search input
        $('#addRemoveSearch').on('input', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();

          addrow.trigger('footable_filter', {
            filter: $(this).val()
          });
        });

        // Add Row Button
        $('#addRowBtn').click(function() {

          //get the footable object
          var footable = addrow.data('footable');

          //build up the row we are wanting to add
          var newRow =
            '<tr><td><button class="btn btn-icon btn-danger btn-outline btn-round btn-xs demo-delete-btn"><i class="icon wb-close-mini" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td><td>Adam</td><td>Doe</td><td>Traffic Court Referee</td><td>22 Jun 1972</td><td><span class="label label-table label-success">Active</span></td></tr>';

          //add it
          footable.appendRow(newRow);
        });
      })();

    })(document, window, jQuery);
  </script>

  </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your first question is an easy enough fix. The `<tr>` elements should be placed inside your php iterator code. As it is now, only one `<tr>` element will be created for all the rows instead of a table row being created for each line of data. so try:

```
<tbody>
<?php
$methodssql = $odb -> query("SELECT * FROM `methods`");

while($row = $methodssql ->fetch())
{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['m_title'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['sub_date'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['author'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['tutorial'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td> <span class="label label-table label-success"> ' . $row['status'] . ' </span> </td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, you have solved it! Praise be for neallred!